# function pointer is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have following problem:

```
void MyClass::LoopFunction(vector<Item>& items,void (MyClass::*funcy)(vector<Item>&,int))
{
    for(SInt32 i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        funcy(items,i);
    }

}
```

It says:

```
Called object type 'void(MyClass::*)(vector<Item>&,int)' is not a function or function pointer
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`funcy` is a pointer to a member function, so you need to call it on an instance of the class, like this:

```
(this->*funcy)(items,i);
```

Comment: yeah now its working, haven't used function pointers for a while :) thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The thing with non-static member functions is that they have an invisible first argument which the compiler will turn into `this` inside the member function. This means that you can't call (non-static) member functions without having an object instance to call the member function on.

In your case, if you want to call it using the `this` objectinside `LoopFunction` you need to do e.g.

```
(this->*funcy)(items, i);
```

If you want to call it on *another* object instance, you need to pass that object to the function, and use that instead.

Or you could use e.g. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead of the member function pointer. Or use a template parameter similar to the way the standard library handles callbacks, and which allows you to pass *any* callable object to the function (still have to use `std::bind` if you want to use a non-static member function though).